# How can i fix this error when installing kivy designer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, windows-10, kivy

Everytime I try to install kivy designer there is an error and whenever I fix one error I find another can someone please help me
I followed the instructions off of this website https://kivy-designer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#id2 and I downloaded all the prerequisites needed
I wrote:
    python -m designer

I get an error of:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Amr\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-02-02_14.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 - Build 23.20.16.4973'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 - Build 23.20.16.4973'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Localization file loaded (C]\Users\Amr\.kivy\garden\garden.xpopup\xpopup.mo).
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: winctypes
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\git\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
     refresh()
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\git\__init__.py", line 73, in refresh
     if not Git.refresh(path=path):
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 290, in refresh
     raise ImportError(err)
 ImportError: Bad git executable.
 The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
     - be included in your $PATH
     - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
     - explicitly set via git.refresh()

 All git commands will error until this is rectified.

 This initial warning can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the
 $GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. Use one of the following values:
     - quiet|q|silence|s|none|n|0: for no warning or exception
     - warn|w|warning|1: for a printed warning
     - error|e|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

 Example:
     export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet


 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
 "__main__", mod_spec)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
 exec(code, run_globals)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\Downloads\kivy-designer-master\kivy-designer-master\designer\__main__.py", line 17, in <module>
 main()
   File "C:\Users\Amr\Downloads\kivy-designer-master\kivy-designer-master\designer\__main__.py", line 13, in main
 DesignerApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 800, in run
 root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\Amr\Downloads\kivy-designer-master\kivy-designer-master\designer\app.py", line 1738, in build
 self.root = Designer()
   File "C:\Users\Amr\Downloads\kivy-designer-master\kivy-designer-master\designer\app.py", line 207, in __init__
 super(Designer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
 super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
 super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 348, in __init__
 Builder.apply(self, ignored_consts=self._kwargs_applied_init)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 469, in apply
 self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule, ignored_consts=ignored_consts)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 585, in _apply_rule
 self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 585, in _apply_rule
 self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 585, in _apply_rule
 self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 544, in _apply_rule
 cls = Factory_get(cname)
   File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 142, in __getattr__
 level=0  # force absolute
   File "C:\Users\Amr\Downloads\kivy-designer-master\kivy-designer-master\designer\tools\git_integration.py", line 23, in <module>
 from git import GitCommandError, RemoteProgress, Repo
    File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\git\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
     raise ImportError('Failed to initialize: {0}'.format(exc))
 ImportError: Failed to initialize: Bad git executable.
The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
 - be included in your $PATH
 - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
 - explicitly set via git.refresh()

 All git commands will error until this is rectified.

 This initial warning can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the
 $GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. Use one of the following values:
     - quiet|q|silence|s|none|n|0: for no warning or exception
     - warn|w|warning|1: for a printed warning
     - error|e|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

 Example:
     export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet
```

I run windows 10 64-bit

If anybody can help I really appreciate it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Have you got git installed and set up as the error message suggests?

Comment: Thanks for that warm welcome...turns out all i needed to do was add git to the path     Thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the directory contains the "git.exe" to the PATH,
Here is how you should do it https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm
(You might need to restart your PC after adding it in order to the process get the new PATH environment var)

Comment: It worked!  Thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: Hi @Python_Master I'm glad I helped you.
Please consider accepting my answer, this will indicate other Stackoverflow users that this solution worked for you.
In addition this will give both of us reputation.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using Stack Overflow...is it the tick?

Answer (score 1):

Kivy Designer is deprecated and doesn't really work, we strongly recommend against using it.

Comment: I tried kivy and i was too confused and couldn't find a decent course to learn from if you could give me a course that would be much appreciated

Comment: @Python_Master there are a number of tutorials covering the basics on YouTube, have you checked there? Picking up a new framework can be daunting at first but it will make sense if you stick to it. There will also be much more help available for working with kivy directly instead of Kivy Designer